# Date Function Returning Null Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, date

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[NewFinishDate]
    (@HourlyQ decimal(18,2), @TotalQ decimal(18,2),
     @Monday integer, @Tuesday integer, @Wednesday integer,
     @Thursday integer, @Friday integer, @Saturday integer, @Sunday integer)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DayName nvarchar(10), @DayHour integer,
            @Calculation Decimal(18,2), @Date as date,
            @i integer, @Finishdate date, @Addeddate date

    SELECT 
        @Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Starting date]) 
    FROM
        [Quantities&Planning]

    WHILE @Calculation < @TotalQ 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @i += 1

        SELECT @Addeddate = DATEADD(DAY, @i, @date)
        SELECT @DayName = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @Addeddate) 

        IF @DayName ='Monday' 
        BEGIN
            set @DayHour = @Monday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end
        else if @DayName ='Tuesday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Tuesday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end

        if @DayName ='Wednesday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Wednesday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end
        else if @DayName ='Thursday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Thursday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end
        else if @DayName ='Friday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Friday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end
        else if @DayName ='Saturday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Saturday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end
        else if @DayName ='Sunday' 
        begin
            set @DayHour = @Sunday
            set @Calculation += @HourlyQ*@DayHour
        end         
    end     

    SELECT
        @Finishdate = DATEADD(DAY, @i, [Starting date]) 
    FROM
        [Quantities&Planning]

    RETURN @Finishdate
END

SELECT
    [dbo].[NewFinishDate](2,5000,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) as Yekeee 
FROM
    [Quantities&Planning]
```

This code is returning NULL values. I have a `[Quantities&Planning]` table and `[StartingDate]` column which is including date type variables. I have tried to return another variable like `nvarchar` and `integer` also. The problem maybe in the while loop.

Comment: It might be best to use "set" rather than "select" for all your assignments. select can do strange things with null values.

Comment: I can't use set when picking values from my table. I also tried with set but still same.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if the occurrences of `FROM [Quantities&Planning]` in your query should be removed. I see nowhere that you actually use any values from `[Quantities&Planning]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you realise that the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    @Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Starting date]) 
FROM
    [Quantities&Planning]
```

Assigns the last `[Starting date]` (minus 1 day) as returned from the whole table `[Quantities&Planning]` to `@Date`? That last row is arbitrary even, as you have no `ORDER BY` clause in your select statement.

The same thing for assigning to `@Finishdate`... You probably want to assign from a specific row, yes? Then add a proper `WHERE` clause that selects only that specific row.

---

Second problem, you never initialize the `@i` variable, so it is `NULL` at the point you run:

```
SELECT @i += 1
```

`@i` will keep being `NULL` for the whole procedure (operations on `NULL` yield `NULL`).

You keep using this `NULL` value to add to dates, and that results in `NULL` values also.

Same problem with `@Calculation`... you need to initialize your variables before using them! It's not because you declare a variable that they are automatically initialized to 0 for integers and decimals. They are initialized as `NULL` unless you initialize them differently.

Comment: declare @Calculation Decimal(18,2) = 0,@i integer = 0 this corrected my fuction. Thank you for your answer.